# Hangman word chosen

Tags: python, graphics

I'm trying to let the user chose the length of the word they want, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is wrong. I'm a noob at Python, I have learned for 3 months and I have searched about Python. I don't know all the Python built in functions or I might know but didn't know how to use them.

Here is my code:

```
from random import *
import os


wordlist_1 = 'cat dog'.split()                #Is all the wordlist be in a function to all three of wordlist?
wordlist_2 = 'donkey monkey dragon'.split()   #Like def wordlist():
wordlist_3 = 'dinosaur alligator buffalo'.split()

keep_playing = True
def print_game_rules(max_incorrect,word_len):
    print"You have only 7 chances to guess the right answer"
    return

def length_1():
    print('You will have length of 3 word')
    return
def length_2():
    print('You will have length of 6 word')
    return
def length_3():
    print('You will have length of 8 word')
    return

def Welcomenote():

    print('Select One Category')
    print(' 1: length of 3 word')
    print(' 2: length of 6 word')
    print(' 3: length of 8 word') 

    choice = {
        "1": length_1,
        "2": length_2,
        "3": length_3 }

    choose = input()
    return

def getrandomword():
    wordindex = random.randint(0,len(wordlist)-1)
    return wordlist[wordindex]

def get_letter():
    print
    letter = raw_input("Guess a letter in the mystery word:") 
    letter = letter.strip()
    letter = letter.lower()
    print
    os.system('cls')
    return letter
def display_figure(hangman):
    graphics = [
    """
         +-------+
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |
     ====================
    """,
    """
         +-------+
         |       |
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |
     ====================
    """,
    """
        +-------+
        |       |
        |       O
        |
        |
        |
        |
    ====================
    """,
    """
        +-------+
        |       |
        |       O
        |       | 
        |
        |
        |
    =====================
    """,
    """
        +-------+
        |       |
        |       O
        |      /| 
        |
        |
        |
    =====================
    """,
    """
        +-------+
        |       |
        |       O
        |      /|\               
        |
        |
        |
    =====================
    """,
    """
        +-------+
        |       |
        |       O
        |      /|\               
        |      /  
        |
        |
    =====================
    """,
    """
        +-------+
        |       |
        |       O
        |      /|\               
        |      / \               
        |
        |
    =====================
    """]

    print graphics[hangman]
    return

while keep_playing:
    word=Welcomenote()
    secretword = getrandomword(word)
    guesses='_' * len(secretword)
    max_incorrect=7
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"
    letters_tried=""
    number_guesses=0
    letters_correct=0
    incorrect_guesses=0
    print_game_rules(max_incorrect,word_len)


    while (incorrect_guesses != max_incorrect) and (letters_correct != secretword):
        letter=get_letter()
        display_figure(incorrect_guesses)
        if len(letter)==1 and letter.isalpha():
            if letters_tried.find(letter) != -1:
                print "You already picked", letter
            else:
                letters_tried = letters_tried + letter
                first_index=word.find(letter)
                if  first_index == -1:
                    incorrect_guesses= incorrect_guesses +1
                    print "The",letter,"is not the mystery word."
                else:
                    print"The",letter,"is in the mystery word."
                    letters_correct=letters_correct+1
                    for i in range(len(secretword)):
                        if letter == secretword[i]:
                            guesses[i] = letter

        else:
            print "Please guess a single letter in the alphabet."

        print ' '.join(guesses)
        print "Letters tried so far: ", letters_tried
        if incorrect_guesses == max_incorrect:
            print "Sorry, too many incorrect guesses. You are hanged."
            print "The word was",word
            keep_playing = False
        if letters_correct == secretword:
            print "You guessed all the letters in the word!"
            print "The word was",word
            keep_playing = False


    if keep_playing == False:
        user = raw_input("\n\tShall we play another game? [y|n] ")
        again = "yes".startswith(user.strip().lower())
        if again:
            keep_playing = True
        else:
            break

raw_input ("\n\n\nPress enter to exit")
```

Now the error says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "P:\Lesson 8\Hangman
>   2 - Copy.py", line 156, in 
>       secretword = getrandomword(word)
>
> TypeError: getrandomword() takes no
>   arguments (1 given)

Comment: You've misspelled `alligator` and `buffalo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the error about `randint` not existing, you've imported the function names in the `random` module.

```
from random import *
```

So just call the function directly.

```
wordindex = randint(0,len(wordlist)-1)
```

So you're not importing more than you have to, I'd suggest importing the module (so you don't need to change the function call) or the single name directly (so you're not polluting the global namespace with the other random functions you don't use).

```
import random
# or
from random import randint
```

---

However there are some other issues in your code.

The variables `length_1`, `length_2` and `length_3` are assigned strings.  Later you redefine them to be functions.  Within those functions your return those names which are functions (not those strings).  Later in `Welcomenote()`, you are returning these functions (not those strings) so it is doubly wrong.  You should be using different names.

Also, it looks like you meant for them to be a list of your words.  If left as is, you will be getting individual letters instead.  It should be a list.  You should define them.

```
wordlist_1 = ['cat', 'dog']
# or alternatively
wordlist_1 = 'cat dog'.split() # splits the string up to a list of words separated by whitespace
```

There are probably others but these are the big ones that stand out and should be fixed.

Comment: Yes, if you would just say `import random`, you'd call it as random.randint, however if you say `from random import randint` or ( `from random import *`), enough to call it with its name.

Comment: i try what you say and the ahmet alp balkan comment, but is come up another error 'TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()'

Comment: @phhnk: That would be a different issue then.  In that case, the value of `wordlist` is `None`.  You'll need to verify beforehand that `wordlist` has a value.

Comment: remove the double quotes around the numbers in your dictionary to get past the None error

Comment: @phhnk check the return value from your `Welcomenote()` routine. It is probably returning `None`. Read up on the difference between `input()` and `raw_input()`.

Comment: @Joseph Gordon you say "the value of `wordlist` is `None`" do you mean like this `def getrandomword():`?
And i had edited the post, could you guys check it?I know is still wrong, but isn't something look like that.

Comment: @phhnk Sorry, I meant that the program is adding entries to choice like this "3": length_3 and this accessing it like this choice[4] instead of choice["4"]. When I removed the double quotes I got the desired value instead of None.